# Is there a terminal-based image viewer that enables directory browsing after viewing a single file?

Tags: linux, command-line, image-viewer

I am searching for a lightweight terminal image viewer like feh,meh, sxiv, pqiv, or qiv, with the end objective of having a terminal image viewer that allows you to explore all pictures in a folder after opening a single image. I also want it to run without requiring the use of the terminal; I want it to be my default program, so that when I double-click a picture, it will open it and allow me to cycle through all the images in the folder.

If there is not any program with the capability, is there any code or a file I can insert in the config folder to enable the capability I am searching for?

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle"? How should this work?